# is it ok to have "short-cut" references to jump over table relations?

Tags: database-design, foreign-key-relationship, relationship

Sorry for the title

I have the following relation, a box belongs to a slot, that belongs to a rack, that belongs to a fridge. The other way around, Fridges have many Racks, that have many slots, that have one box.

For some operations, knowing where the box is within the fridge is not necessary. It would simplify some queries if I had a short-cut from boxes to fridges.

Is it bad, and if so why, to have a foreign key to the fridge in the boxes table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could depend on how often the relation will be updated.  If the relation is likely to change frequently then you would have the overhead of having to update the relationship in several places.  This can also make things slightly more difficult too because if you change one you have to make sure that all occurrences are updated as well.

However, if the values are not going to change that often it seems like it could make your queries faster.

[This](http://www.phlonx.com/resources/nf3/) looks like it is a pretty good example of database normalization and the example that they use is fairly close to yours.  If you are interested in normalization the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) article on this is really good.

Comment: If you use a database that supports referential integrity enforcement of constraints, then the database will help you avoid programming code that forgets to update the foreign-parent key in the denormalized table.

Comment: Yes I agree.  Though I did not see the type of database that was being used in the question so I only included because it is something additional that you would need to account for in one form or another.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and comments. I should have mentionned that I'm using MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

By recording the fridge association with a box in two different places you create the possibility of a contradiction arising. Therefore you would either have to create extra constraint logic to ensure the redundant data was consistent or accept that the data might be wrong.